# Picasso's Target and centerCrop() and fit()

Tags: android, picasso

I have an image on my server and I want to display it using Picasso on my Android client.
I want to add a default image when the image is loading on Picasso so I am using `Target` as follows:

```
Picasso.with(UserActivity.this).load(imageUri.toString()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(500, 1)).into(
new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        userPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        userPic.setImageBitmap(defaultDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
        userPic.setImageBitmap(defaultDrawable);
    }
});
```

I want to `centerCrop()` and `fit()` this image but it gives me an error and it tells me that I cant use them with Target. Is there anyway to use these features on Picasso? Why don't they allow these two functions with `Target`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to use `Target` to accomplish your goal.

Side note, I am not certain that you can actually use both `fit()` and `centerCrop()` together.

See this [example](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url) // Equivalent of what ends up in onBitmapLoaded
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // Equivalent of what ends up in onPrepareLoad
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // Equivalent of what ends up in onBitmapFailed
    .centerCrop()
    .fit()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: you can use `fit()` and `centerCrop()` together. no problem

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .fit()
  .placeholder(defaultImageLink)
  .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
  .transform(new RoundedTransformation(500, 1))
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also resize the image as required by the imageview which will save memory usage if the image too large.

Callback method can be used to hide the progress bar and show some text within the image View on image load fail.

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_img)
.error(R.drawable.error_img)
.resize(450, 420)
.centerCrop()
.fit()
.into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            image_failed_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```