# How to resize images to fit in card view properly

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview, image-resizing

Hello I'm trying to resize images to the size of the card view but some images fit properly and some of them don't I want that all the images fit into the card view properly

I have used all scale type but the best I found is center crop but still after using it some images doesn't fit properly

here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="13dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="4dp">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside card view use:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's a built-in way to accomplish this.

Also "fit" suggests your target `ImageView` and the image you want to display on it, have the same width to height ratio. Otherwise, while you can "fit" it, the image will be squished or stretched in one dimension.

Once you confirm that, you can use one of the many image processing libraries to do this.

Popular ones are

- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
- [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)

Both Glide and Picasso have very similar APIs, so if you pick one and later want to change to the other, it is very easy.

Checkout  the [FitCenter transformation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html) for Glide. I think that's what you're looking for, however remember that if your widt to height ratio doesn't match, the image will look weird.

If you want Picasso instead, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34940604).